# Encoding my Bitcoin Address with Base58 encoding

Tags: address, bitcoinj, base58

I am trying to convert my Bitcoin Address with BitcoinJ in order to look like a normal address such as this:
1J7mdg5rbQyUHENYdx39WVWK7fsLpEoXZy.

I haven't found anything exept for the `Base58.encode()` which takes the `getPubkeyHash()` of my `ECKey` and returns something like this:
5ahorsFsHTcG3f662evowc5c9zf.

Which means that encodes the given bytes in base58,no checksum is appended according to the API.But i want my address to look like the above one.

Is there any algorithm in java  for **encoding address_byte_string (consisting of 1-byte_version + hash_or_other_data + 4-byte_check_code)**?

according to this:https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

```
ECKey key = ...;
String addr = key.toAddress(MainNetParams.get()).toString();
```

https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.12/org/bitcoinj/core/ECKey.html#toAddress-org.bitcoinj.core.NetworkParameters-

Comment: thanks for your answer.The key.toAddress() function was the one that i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not Java, but interesting to examine as a reference to explore Java functionality with this fc8fba997174132184998ab82b28e441e80c73236ccaf8b6a1efadc33febecfc  being a secp256k1 elliptic curve private key.

1. `% echo fc8fba997174132184998ab82b28e441e80c73236ccaf8b6a1efadc33febecfc | bx ec-to-public -u | bx sha256 | bx ripemd160 | bx wrap-encode -v 0 | bx base58-encode`
   **1KNogjhyQ3fSPGpzgAv8gSG5WLVN8L39Ln**
2. `% echo fc8fba997174132184998ab82b28e441e80c73236ccaf8b6a1efadc33febecfc | bx ec-to-public -u | bx sha256 | bx ripemd160 | bx base58check-encode -v 0`
   **1KNogjhyQ3fSPGpzgAv8gSG5WLVN8L39Ln**
3. `% echo fc8fba997174132184998ab82b28e441e80c73236ccaf8b6a1efadc33febecfc | bx ec-to-public -u | bx bitcoin160 | bx base58check-encode -v 0`
   **1KNogjhyQ3fSPGpzgAv8gSG5WLVN8L39Ln**
4. `% echo fc8fba997174132184998ab82b28e441e80c73236ccaf8b6a1efadc33febecfc | bx ec-to-public -u | bx bitcoin160 | bx address-encode -v 0`
   **1KNogjhyQ3fSPGpzgAv8gSG5WLVN8L39Ln**
5. `% echo fc8fba997174132184998ab82b28e441e80c73236ccaf8b6a1efadc33febecfc | bx ec-to-public | bx bitcoin160 | bx address-encode -v 0`
   **1FbGdbUU1ibBtanPTLAuMTAJ4Y9HkatkcX**
6. `% echo fc8fba997174132184998ab82b28e441e80c73236ccaf8b6a1efadc33febecfc | bx ec-to-public`
   **02cf90dc2b34937fff7cf1eb4b260f1e5610231134b864761e508505938bbef8fc**
7. `% echo fc8fba997174132184998ab82b28e441e80c73236ccaf8b6a1efadc33febecfc | bx ec-to-public -u`
   **04cf90dc2b34937fff7cf1eb4b260f1e5610231134b864761e508505938bbef8fc00aeb265797336b74146e018da7b78070f1f1072540a2c3fe83637ca5d605b3c**
8. `% echo fc8fba997174132184998ab82b28e441e80c73236ccaf8b6a1efadc33febecfc | bx ec-to-public -u | bx bitcoin160`
   **c991f856a2992c877d3923298e67b88fe61e6c76**